# merge and count in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array

```
Array
(
    [array_name_1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 1
            [4] => 1
        )

    [array_name_2] => Array
        (
            [5] => 1
            [6] => 1
            [7] => 1
            [8] => 1
            [9] => 1
            [10] => 1
        )
)
```

I want to merge and calculate the number of arrays above so that it becomes

```
array
(
[array_name_1] => 5
[array_name_2] => 6
)
```

can anyone help to provide a solution? thank you

Comment: `echo count($array, true);`  Which is 13, who know about that second argument --

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use foreach loop

```
  $finalArr = [];
  foreach($yourMainArr as $key => $arr){
    $finalArr[$key] = count($arr);
  }
  print_r($finalArr);
```